# what could be xpath or css for following snippet

Tags: css, xpath, selenium

click
 //div[15]/div/ul/li[5]

In the snippet above, how can I write xpath or css selector based on known li item. Yes, I know li item ahead of time(such as @, +, * etc ) Also there is no guarantee that div[15] would be always div[15] it could be div[14] or div[17] etc

Comment: What makes that item unique? is there text or is there link in it?

Comment: hi there, yes, text makes item unique

Answer (score 0):

Would need more information to give a good answer, but some suggestions are below:

If you want to select the 5th `<li>` in the entire HTML document:

```
xpath=/descendant::li[5]
```

I'm not sure what you mean by "I know li item ahead of time(such as @, +, * etc )" but if you know a unique attribute of the `<li>` you can use that to locate it:

If you know the `@id` of the `<li>`:

```
id=knownId
```

If you know a CSS class of the `<li>`:

```
css=li.knownClass
xpath=//li[contains(@class, 'knownClass']
```

If you know the text of the `<li>`:

```
css=li:contains(knownText)
xpath=li[contains(text(), 'knownText')]
```

Hope that helps. Some more information - ideally a snippet of you HTML - would help to give a more specific answer.

Comment: Hi Dave, thank you for your response with multiple answer options. 

I tried following 
click("css=li:contains("+variable +")"); //doesn't work
click(//div[15]/div/ul/li[contains(text(), '"+variable +"')]"); //work

and second command works but I have to pass DIV[IndexNumber] which in this case is DIV[15] which I'm not happy about it

Comment: Can you provide a snippet of your HTML?

Comment: li dynamic menu is accessed by clicking on span[2] which is either one of item in list menu.

In following scenario, I click on span[2], then dynamic menu opens where it allows me to choose one of value from it's menu. In following scenario, I repeated same procedure couple of time.

Comment: <tr>
 <td>click</td>
 <td>//div[@id='myid']/div/div/span[2]</td>
 <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>click</td>
 <td>//div[21]/div/ul/li[5]</td>
 <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>click</td>
 <td>//div[@id='myid']/div/div/span[2]</td>
 <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>click</td>
 <td>//div[22]/div/ul/li[7]</td>
 <td></td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
</body>
</html>

Comment: Could you provide the relevant HTML source from your application? I suggest adding it to your original question for readability.